# grails, which jquery event handler to bind to element updates made by remoteFunction or remoteLink

Tags: jquery, grails

In the remoteFunction and remoteLink tags one can list a map of elements to update with the server response.  When the call is done, these elements will be updated.

Using jquery, which event handler can one bind to the element(s) to determine that an update to the element has occurred?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the onComplete attribute of g:remoteFunction? Whatever javascript you specify in the onComplete attribute of the remoteFunction or remoteLink tag will be executed upon completion of the request and updates being finished. You can then put in that function to make the jQuery calls you want

```
<g:remoteFunction action="show" id="1" update="someElement" onComplete="callMe()" />
<script>
   function callMe() {
      // Do your jQuery stuff here. Elements have been updated on the page.
   }
</script>
```

If you need to know success or failure, you could use the onSuccess or onFailure attributes of the tag.

See this page in the grails docs for more info: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html

Comment: Thanks Todd, I need to try to remember why either a) I did not find this to work or b) wasn't unaware of that as a solution.  I posted some time ago, so hopefully my mind will do a refresh here soon as I revisit the issue.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Didn't see the date you posted, but hopefully the answer is still useful to you or someone else. :)